# Searching a particular string in a large file

Tags: c, search

I am making program in C which can search for a specific string in a large **.txt** file and **count it and then print it out**. But it seems that something have go wrong, cause the output of my program is different from that of the two text editor. According to the text editor, there are totally 3000 words,in this case I search for the word "make", in that **.txt** file. But the output of my program is just 2970.

I cannot find out the problem of my program. So I am curios about how could a text editor search for a specific string so accurately? How do people implement that? Can any people show me some code in C?

To make things clear: that is a large **.txt** file, 20M or so, containing lots of characters. So I think it's not so good to read it into memory all at once. I have implement my program by splitting my program in to pieces and then scan all of those for parsing. However, it fail some way.

Maybe I should put the code here. Wait a minute please.

The code is kinda long, 70 lines or so. I have put it on my github, if you have any interest, please help. https://github.com/walkerlala/searchText
note that the only related file is **wordCount.c** and **testfile.txt** which goes like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
char arr[51];
int flag=0;
int flag2=0;
int flag3=0;
int flag4=0;
int pieceCount(FILE*);
int main()
{
     //the file in which I want to search the word is testfile.txt
    //I have formatted the file so that it contain no newlins any more
    FILE* fs=fopen("testfile.txt","r");
    int n=pieceCount(fs);
    printf("%d\n",n);           



    rewind(fs);         //refresh the file...

    static bool endOfPiece1=false,endOfPiece2=false,endOfPiece3=false;
    bool begOfPiece1,begOfPiece2,begOfPiece3;

    for(int start=0;start<n;++start){
            fgets(arr,sizeof(arr),fs);
            for(int i=0;i<=46;++i){
                if((arr[i]=='M'||arr[i]=='m')&&(arr[i+1]=='A'||arr[i+1]=='a')&&(arr[i+2]=='K'||arr[i+2]=='k')&&(arr[i+3]=='E'||arr[i+3]=='e')){
                    flag+=1;
                    //continue;
                }
        }


    //check the border
        begOfPiece1=((arr[1]=='e'||arr[1]=='E'));
        if(begOfPiece1==true&&endOfPiece1==true)
            flag2+=1;
        endOfPiece1=((arr[47]=='m'||arr[47]=='M')&&(arr[48]=='a'||arr[48]=='A')&&(arr[49]=='k'||arr[49]=='K'));

        begOfPiece2=((arr[1]=='k'||arr[1]=='K')&&(arr[2]=='e'||arr[2]=='E'));
        if(begOfPiece2==true&&endOfPiece2==true)
            flag3+=1;
        endOfPiece2=((arr[48]=='m'||arr[48]=='M')&&(arr[49]=='a'||arr[49]=='A'));

        begOfPiece3=((arr[1]=='a'||arr[1]=='A')&&(arr[2]=='k'||arr[2]=='K')&&(arr[3]=='e'||arr[3]=='E'));
        if(begOfPiece3==true&&endOfPiece3==true)
            flag4+=1;
        endOfPiece3=(arr[49]=='m'||arr[49]=='M');

} 
  printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",flag,flag2,flag3,flag4);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//the function counts how many pieces have I split the file into
int pieceCount(FILE* file){
    static int count=0;
    char arr2[51]={'\0'};
  while(fgets(arr2,sizeof(arr),file)){
        count+=1;
        continue;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess. Maybe the words you don't find are on the border between two "pieces" you read, E.g: you search for "ABC", piece 1 : "123AB", piece 2: "CDEXYZ"

Comment: try on smaller input. Find the smallest input for which your program output differ from vim. Debug/try to figure out what messes up your algorithm. Fix it. Be happy.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  I would. wait a minute please

Comment: look where your test txt file is being split. That's the hot spot I'd look for those missing 30 occurences. Add information how you split your file, this might be helpful. Generate a file consisting only of word you want to look. One being split, one that doesn't, if the output of latter is wrong-> here's your answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz@zubergu@bolov I have put on my code. please check

Comment: Well I have add my code. Hopefully it can be reopened.

Comment: That's an extraordinary piece of code. You split a file into 50-byte pieces and are checking for the existence of the hard-coded word `"make"` in upper or lower case letter by letter, and trying to bridge block boundaries. It's a hiding to nowhere. If your input file of 20Mbytes is "too big to read" (on my system I have over 2Gbytes available), why don't you just read it char by char and maintain a current buffer of 4 bytes, the length of `"make"`?

Comment: Apart from the framework and opening / closing the file, it can be done in 10 lines of code.         `char buff[4];
        int count = 0;
        if (4 == fread(buff, 1, 4, fs)) {
            do {
                if (strnicmp(buff, "make", 4) == 0)
                    count++;
                memmove(buff, buff+1, 3);
            } while (1 == fread(buff+3, 1, 1, fs));
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);`

Comment: .. @WeatherVane:  that is even better, it's just *one* line of code!

Comment: @Jongware ended up with an answer of 21 lines.

Comment: Text editors typically store the entire file in memory, and have no need to deal with strings crossing any kind of buffer boundaries. Tools like `grep` process files a line at a time, and either limit the length of a line or (like GNU grep) allocate as much space as is needed for each line; a word like `"make"` cannot cross a line boundary.

Comment: @KeithThompson wouldn't it consume up the memory if it store the entire file in it? I mean, even though it do not consume up the memory, it will also take up too many place in the memory, thus slow down other process  in the same computer. Isn't there a "buffer" or something that text editor use to handle this problem?

Comment: @walkerlala: Most text files I edit are much smaller than the memory my system has. Loading the entire file into memory makes operations on it *much* faster. If you try to edit a file that won't fit in memory, some editors might swap parts of it to disk. Or, more likely, they might just slurp the whole file into memory anyway, and count on the OS's virtual memory system to do the right thing. See also `mmap`.

Comment: @KeithThompson  
I have modified my code a little bit (moving the declaration of those bool values out of the for loop to make things more clear). It does give me a right number of pieces totally. But I can't get the exact number (2035) as Weather Vane's program have does (it give me 1933, far away from the right answer). Could you help me find out the bugs in my code? I try to debug it but fail. I thinks that it might be some buffer issues...

Answer (score 5):

You can do this quite simply just by having a rolling buffer. You don't need to break the file into sections.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char buff [4];                                  // word buffer
    int count = 0;                                  // occurrences
    FILE* fs=fopen("test.txt","r");                 // open the file
    if (fs != NULL) {                               // if the file opened
        if (4 == fread(buff, 1, 4, fs)) {           // fill the buffer
            do {                                    // if it worked
                if (strnicmp(buff, "make", 4) == 0) // check for target word
                    count++;                        // tally
                memmove(buff, buff+1, 3);           // shift the buffer down
            } while (1 == fread(buff+3, 1, 1, fs)); // fill the last position
        }                                           // end of file
        fclose(fs);                                 // close the file
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);                          // report the result
    return 0;
}
```

For simplicity I stopped short of making the search word "softer" and allocating the correct buffer and various sizes, since that wasn't in the question. And I have to leave something for OP to do.

Comment: That is so cool !!! especially when you shift the buffer one byte by one byte using `do{...} while(1==(fread(buff+3,1,1,fs))`....However, I wonder wheter it will slow down the speed to load data indirectly from a file(stream) rather than memeory? Originally, the reason why I split the text and load it into an array of 51 bytes was that I think it would me faster for the CPU to load data from memory than from a file (stream).

Comment: Although your question title referred to **text editor**, my answer was directed at the detail of the question, as you search a file for a string. Nothing really to do with a text editor but @KeithThompson wrote a good remark "Text editors typically store the entire file in memory". Note too, that a text search in an editor won't look for a word that crosses a line break.

Comment: wouldn't it consume up (or use too much) the memory if it a text editor store the entire file in the memory? ....ps,I was doing a little project which is related to a text editor. But I think it's good to change the title.

Comment: @walkerlala the memory is there for *you* to use, not somebody else. My system has 2GB free at the moment. That could hold 100 of the 20Mb files you mention in an editor's tabs.

Comment: Another thing that I am confused about is, when don't you flush the stream after using `fread()`? I don't get when the stream will be flushed in your code, can you tell me?

Comment: I have modified my code a little bit (moving the declaration of those `bool` values out of the for loop to make things more clear). It does give me a right number of piece totally. But I can't get the exact number (`2035`) as your program have does (it give me `1933`, far away from the right answer). Could you help me find out the bug in my code?

Comment: @walkerlala presumably your `flag2` etc are still `0` since you didn't increment them in your boundary test. Your boolean tests should be setting `flag2+=1` (etc), but instead you conditionally set `endOfPiece1` (etc). Also you are not checking the array properly. The first byte of the array is `arr[0]`, not `arr[1]` (etc).

Comment: @walkerlala you don't flush an input stream, and why would I anyway? Open file, read until no more data, close file - end of.

Comment: May I ask you a question? It seems like that you are a skilled programmer. So, normally, are you used to flushing the stream when you want the input or output? Or is it a good habit to flush a stream any time you want some input or output? If not, then when is it necessary or goog for a programmer to flush a stream manually? If you may, please give me some personal advice. Thank you.

Comment: @walkerlala flushing streams: I only flush an output stream by using a `newline` (ie `\n`) for a text file, or by closing the file, or with `fflush` if really needed. I sometimes flush an input stream when I want to clean off any buffered input. Two examples 1) using `scanf` to input a char when I have just input a value ending in a `newline`, which remains in the buffer. 2) when I want to confirm an action like "Do you really want to destroy the world?" I will clear off any type-ahead in the input buffer. As for my skill, thank you but I only know what I know.